# "Get an API key" on stackapps.com/about page is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed

the "Get an API key" link listed on the [stackapps about page](https://stackapps.com/about) is incorrect. It points to https://stackapps.com/app/register and a lovely picture of Zardoz instead of the correct https://stackapps.com/apps/register page.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed.